# awk: print lines that DO NOT match patterns in a file, looking at a specific column

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, bioinformatics, text-processing

I have an `idFile`:

```
1006006
1006008
1006011
1007002
......
```

and `famFile`:

```
1006 1006001 1006016 1006017 1
1006 1006006 1006016 1006017 1
1006 1006007 0       0       2
1006 1006008 1006007 1006006 2
1006 1006010 1006016 1006017 2
1006 1006011 1006016 1006017 1
1006 1006016 0       0       2
1006 1006017 0       0       1
1007 1007001 1007950 1007015 2
1007 1007002 1007014 1007015 2
......
```

I need to grep all the lines from `famFile` where the second column **does not** match any of the lines in `idFile`.

[This command:](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/163391-grep-specific-column-one-file-based-another-file-please-help.html)

```
awk 'BEGIN { while(getline <"idFile") id[$0]=1; }
id[$2] ' famFile
```

returns all the matches:

```
1006 1006006 1006016 1006017 1
1006 1006008 1006007 1006006 2
1006 1006011 1006016 1006017 1
1007 1007002 1007014 1007015 2
......
```

But how can I modify the command to get the complement of the matches?

Comment: That command you posted is buggy. I guess the lesson is to be wary of any script you get from a reference entitled "unix for dummies"! See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to use getline correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($2 in a)' idFile famFile
1006 1006001 1006016 1006017 1
1006 1006007 0       0       2
1006 1006010 1006016 1006017 2
1006 1006016 0       0       2
1006 1006017 0       0       1
1007 1007001 1007950 1007015 2
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                  # process the idFile
    a[$1]                  # hash to a 
    next                   # next id
}
!($2 in a)                 # if the second field id is not in a, output record
' idFile famFile           # mind the file order
```

Comment: `$2 in a==0` is odd syntax vs `!($2 in a)`.